# definitions of martingals

Tags: probability, martingales, conditional-expectation

Let X - discrete time stochastic process

A discrete-time martingale: is $E[|X_{n}|] < \infty$
$$
E[X_{n+1}|X_{1}, X_{2}, ..., X_{n}] = X_{n}.
$$

The definition of martingale for filtration:

$$
E[X_{n}|F_{m}] = X_{m},
$$ 
here ${F_{m}}$ is a filtration and the process is adapted.

The question is: how can we get the first definition from the second one?

Answer (score 1):

Let the filtration be $\mathcal{F}_n=\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$, i.e., the smallest sigma field such that each of $X_1,\dots, X_n$ are measurable with respect to it. Conditioning on $X_1,\dots,X_n$ is equivalent to conditioning on $\mathcal{F}_n$, so according to the second definition we have $E[X_{n+1}|X_1,\dots,X_n]=E[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]=X_n$.

Note in your definition of martingale for a filtration you should have $m \leq n$. If $m>n$, then $X_n \in \mathcal{F}_m$, so $E[X_n |\mathcal{F}_m]=X_n$.

Comment: Why is the conditioning on $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{n}$ equivalent to the one on filtration??? This is analogous construction with the same properties, but conditioning on random variables is conditioning on event - which means on sen. Conditioning on filtration is about sigma algebra. This is different object!

Comment: Check out page 192 here https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf and the formal definition on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable_2. As you have written it, you are conditioning on _random variables_, not events. Expectation conditional on a random variable is defined to be expectation conditional on the sigma algebra it generates.

Comment: Yes... I see.... Thank you.